# Using bootstrap-vue <b-form-tags> as custom Django admin widget

Tags: django, bootstrap-vue, python-3.8

I'm attempting add one of these cool [bootstrap-vue tag inputs](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-tags/#basic-usage) to my Django admin page and I'm having a difficult time getting it to render properly. Unfortunately there's a lot of customization on my part that I feel may be interfering with the rendering on the templates but I feel as though I haven't done anything too out of the ordinary. Such as:

**admin.py**

```
# I added custom models form reference and added all the required files to my Meta class
class IngredientAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    form = IngredientListForm
    model = IngredientList
    class Media:
        js = [
            'tagwidget/js/polyfill.min.js',
            'tagwidget/js/vue.min.js',
            'tagwidget/js/bootstrap-vue.min.js'
        ]   
        css = {'all':(
            'tagwidget/css/tabbed_admin.css',
            'tagwidget/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'tagwidget/css/bootstrap-vue.min.css',
            )
        }
```

**forms.py**
    #I added a custom widget, form, and added my template too the render method. Pretty sure this is where I'm lost.

```
class TagWidget(forms.Widget):
    template_name = 'admin/chemicals/includes/tag_widget.html'

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, renderer=None):
        context = self.get_context(name, value, attrs)
        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name).render(context)
        return mark_safe(template)

class IngredientListForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = IngredientList
        widgets = {
            'cas_number': TagWidget(),
        }
        fields = '__all__'
```

And then my tag_widget.html template, which renders the field as blank

```
<div id="tagwidget">
  <template>
    <b-form-tags v-model="value" no-outer-focus class="mb-2">
    </b-form-tags>
    </template>
  </div>
<script>
  Vue.config.devtools = true
  var tagwidget = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    el: '#tagwidget',
    data() {
      return {
              value:['TEST']
            }
    },
    methods: {}
    });
</script>
```

I'm feeling a little lost in the woods. I've tried things like moving the Vue components into and out of the admins fieldsets.html and change_form.html templates but that seemed to make the page lose scope of elements because I would get "value" not defined errors in the browser console. What's strange is [I got this to work](https://github.com/D2theR/django-tabbed-admin/blob/master/tabbed_admin/templates/tabbed_admin/change_form.html#L20) fairly well with the [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/tabs/#basic-usage) tabs by changing up the delimiters for Vue.

Answer (score 0):

So, being that I'm still kinda new to vue-bootstrap and vue in general I figured I was missing a file somewhere that never got copied properly into my static directory... I was correct.

There are two different settings.py files, development and production. The only major difference between the two is Debug=True and one loads django-debug-toolbar. Checking the static files between the two settings I TOTALLY forgot that in production Django tries to look for .min.js and min.css files first, I think? For whatever reason in production I got a browser console warning that it couldn't find **bootstrap-vue.min.js.map**. I'm currently using vue-bootstrap 2.6.1 so re-downloaded all of the files for the new 2.7.0, including the .map file and BOOM! Fancy tag widget!

For anyone wondering I ended up removing my  tag from the widget.html page and adding it to all my static files to my admin model Meta class and it worked fine.

```
class Media:
        js = [
            "tabbed_admin/js/polyfill.min.js",
            "tabbed_admin/js/vue.min.js",
            "tabbed_admin/js/bootstrap-vue.min.js",
            "tabbed_admin/js/bootstrap-vue.min.js.map"
            "tabbed_admin/js/boostrap-vue-tag.js"
        ]   
        css = {'all':(
            'tabbed_admin/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'tabbed_admin/css/bootstrap-vue.min.css',
            )
        }
```